# Lua wont overwrite nil value

Tags: lua

I have an sql statement that could return a result or not.  If it doesn't return a result I need to change the nil value to "none".  I cant seem to figure out how to do this.  I have put my code in pcall can still wont get overwritten.  I keep getting "attempt to index a nil value" in the if statement line.  I am running lua 5.2.3 on Debian 8.  What am I missing?

```
--if ( SqlConnect(number).status == nil or SqlConnect(number).status == '') then
if pcall( SqlConnect(number).status ) then
    result = "none"
else
    result = SqlConnect(number).status
end
```

Comment: A few questions: what type does SqlConnect(number) return? Where is the error thrown exactly? What type is SqlConnect(number).status? We'll need more information to answer properly.

Answer (score 1):

Combine pcall() with assert() like...

```
if pcall(assert,SqlConnect(number).status) then return true else return false end
```

...then do what you have to do in the true or false section.
Lets say you need the value then do your pcall() in the true section to get the value and the fallback case in the false section.

Comment: I have added the assert piece as described above and I am still getting the attempt to index a nil value.  I have tested it with a value that is valid and it works fine.

Comment: I just copied your pcall(assert) statement, literally just copied and pasted it into my code and the lua script fails on "if pcall" line. with "attempt to index a nil value stack traceback."

Answer (score 0):

If pcall returns as a success, and a proper value was given, then it just uses that.  Otherwise, it replaces with your 'none' result.

```
local success, result = pcall( SqlConnect(number).status )

if not success or result == '' or type( result ) == nil then
    result = 'none'
end
```

**Edit** -- same thing, just strike that, reverse it:

```
if not success or type( result ) == nil or result == '' then
```

---

**Edit:**

pcall() probably wants *just that function* as an arg, and not the appended `.status`.
I'm not certain, but if I had to guess, that's why it was failing.
https://riptutorial.com/lua/example/16000/using-pcall

---

Here's how'd you'd write it as an xpcall:

```
function try()
    attempt = SqlConnect( number ) .status or 'none'  --  if nil, replace with 'none'
    if attempt == '' then attempt = 'none' end  --  replace blank strings with 'none'
    return attempt
end

function except()  --  if call to `SqlConnect( number )` completely fails
    return 'none'
end

success, result = xpcall( try, except )
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_error_handling.htm

Comment: I copied and pasted your code into my script and I am getting "attempt to index a nil value" on the first line.  local success........  SqlConnect(number).status prints out a value when there is one.  I am just trying to print "none" if there is no value.

Comment: oh yea, reverse the order on the `== ''`  it'll see the nil before it sees a blank space...

Comment: it is not even getting to the if statement.  It is giving me the error on the local success line.  Just tested it on a value that is on the DB and it works fine.

Comment: Not entirely surprised.  I've had better success with xpcall in the past.  Worded a bit differently, but seems to run without crashing out, better than pcall.  You got it running though?

Comment: not yet.  Still trying to get the correct syntax.  "result ret, err = xpcall(SqlConnect.status, debug.traceback);" is not working for me.